# Damp exterior bricks near the roof and windows

Tags: brick, mold, damp-proof-course

I been looking everywhere.

Some say it could be a drainage issue or mold.

Would anyone know what could cause this discoloration?

[image]

Comment: You say damp, do you know it is damp?

Comment: I do not know sir, it's been like this even on hot days

Comment: Sir? well aren't you just an Angel. Other then aesthetics does it pose a problem or do you just want to make sure there is no problem?

Comment: I plan on buying this unit I want to ensure this won't be a problem down the road. Looks like water may need to drain from roof or something along those lines

Comment: Will you not have an inspection done to learn about such things?